# Introduce a table which takes all the width of a current article page (with 2 columns writting text) and continue after to write text on 2 columns

Tags: tables, two-column, width, article, paper

I am writing a scientific article and I neeed help to put a table taking all the width of
paper (which is writing on main both text columns).

Here is an example of these main both text columns :

[image: example of 2 columns of text]

I would like to introduce in the middle of the current page (above `8.2 Final results`) and on all the width of the paper the following table :

[image]

while being able to take over, after having introduced it, the following text writting on 2 columns.

Does anyone know what is the trick to apply to do that ?

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: Adding a wide table in the middle of a page of a two column document interrupts the text flow to some extent. How is the reader supposed to read the text around the table? top left -> top right -> bottom left -> bottom right or top left -> bottom left -> top right -> bottom right?

Comment: the document class is : `\documentclass[longauth]{aa}`

Comment: below the table, the classical text flow continues classicaly, top left up to bottom left and right top up to bottom right